# Unable to determine when asterisk (*) is passed as argument to script

Tags: bash, shell

here's my code:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "no params"
elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ "$1" = "*" ] ; then
    # do something
    else echo "bad params"
    fi
else echo "more than 1 param"
fi
```

The problem is when I start script with

```
 sh script.sh *
```

it will print more than 1 param  `cause the " * " will search for all files`  ,

and my question is how to disable to search files.

Comment: What happens if you escape the asterisk? e.g. `\*`?

Comment: `"*"` doesn't expand to all files. Are you sure you are calling it with `"*"` and not just `*`? I just tested your script and with `"*"` it does the expected behavior (`# do something`).

Comment: Im sorry im not good at english and i didnt understand u well

Comment: Can't reproduce that in bash (though I had to add a simple `echo` in the `if [ "$1" = "*" ] ; then` portion to make it work of course). `sh ./script.sh "*"` just works here, I only get an error with `sh ./script.sh *`, which you cannot prevent in your script itself. Are you calling it in any way that might strip the quotes?

Comment: @user3381194 He says that this can't be your actual code because what you posted works as it should.

Comment: i edited it sorry its only * not "*"

Comment: @user3381194 That is the problem. You have to run it with `"*"`, otherwise `*` expands to the files in your current directory.

Comment: and is there something to make only * work ?

Comment: @user3381194, not something you can do inside the script, no. You could turn off globbing, but that would have serious side effects (commands that depend on globbing, like `ls *.txt`, would no longer work).

Comment: okey thanks ill try something else

Answer (score 2):

A script can't tell if it was passed an unquoted `*` as an argument or a list of files, because before the shell actually invokes the script, it replaces the `*` with the list of files which that wildcard would match.

Thus, the behavior you're requesting is not possible without requiring the user to quote:

```
your-script '*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Either quote the asterisk to prevent the shell from expanding it

```
sh script.sh "*"
```

or disable file name generation first:

```
set -f
sh script.sh *
set +f          # Re-enable afterwards
```

The second method isn't really recommended; leaving file name expansion turned off can have unexpected consequences later, and it's a lot of typing compared to simply quoting the asterisk.

Comment: It's worth noting that `set -f` will break all manner of common interactive usages of the shell.

Comment: Good point; it's an available option, but not really suitable for short-term use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the asterisk `*`, otherwise it gets expanded to the files in your current directory (see [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)).

```
$ sh script.sh "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ echo *   # Note: No quotation marks
```

You'll get a listing of your files and directories.

Now try this:

```
$ echo "*"   # Note the quotes around the asterisk
```

Here, you'll get just an asterisk.

Before your program can execute, the shell grabs the arguments and expands them.

This is because the shell in Unix is quite intelligent. It's good because it means that my programs do not have to interpret what `*.txt` means. The shell handles that. It also means that if I want to pass `*` to a shell script, I need to *quote* it.

Quoting can usually be done in one three ways:

- **Using double quotes**: `$echo "*"`
- **Using single quotes**: `$echo '*'
- **Using a backslash**: `$echo \*`

Using double quotes is pretty much the standard. It doesn't completely stop the shell from mucking up your command line. The shell will interpolate shell variables, but it will stop what is called *globbing* where the shell will try to expand out specialized characters into file names.

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo "$foo *"
$ echo bar *
```

Using single quotes will keep the shell completely out of the way. It won't even attempt to interpolate variables.

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo '$foo *'
$foo *
```

Using a backslash prevents the shell from doing anything with the next character. It's like single quotes, but you don't have to worry about the closing quote:

```
$ echo \$foo \*
$ $foo *
```

So, there's nothing wrong with your shell script. Your shell script is detecting whether or not an asterisk is being passed to it. The problem is that the shell is intercepting the arguments you are passing to your command, seeing the asterisk, and replacing it with a list of all the files in your directory before your program even begins to execute.

You can see this by typing the following command:

$ set -xv

Now, try running your program as is with the asterisk.

$ myprog *

The `set -xv` command will show you what the shell is passing to your program before your program executes it. The `set -xv`, but they way, is very helpful in debugging shell scripts, so it's nice to know.

To turn off `set -xv`, type this:

```
$ set +xv
```